# A continue function is injective?

Tags: functions

Is a continue function injective? I have to prove that a function is injectiv. Is it enough if i prove that the function is continue?

Comment: No: every constant function is continuous, and a constant function is never injective unless its domain has only one point.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean continuous.  But the answer is: no.  Just take $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, defined by $f(x) = 0$, a continuous function which is not injective...